# Problems activating Facebook Ads in iOS App

Tags: ios, facebook, ads, facebook-audience-network, facebook-monetization-manager

I am trying to integrate Facebook Ads in my iOS App.
I have the SDK installed and I also already receive test-ads. So everything seems to work fine.

BUT...

On the Facebook page inside the Monetization Manager there is a 4 step tutorial on what I need to do.

1. was Choosing the ad format -> Banner -> Done
2. Integrating the SDK (I'd say it's done cause I see Test-Ads inside my app) but here's the problem... Cause there is no Checkmark there.
3. Is the payment info. That's done.
4. Would be the Review that I'd like to do, but that seems to be deactivated...

So... It also says there, that I need to be logged in to facebook on my phone with an associated Account. I am!
I don't know what else I'd need to do in order for Facebook to recognize that I already successfully displayed a Test-Ad and I just can't find any contact phone number to ask somebody.

Any hints are very much appreciated.
Btw. I already tried yesterday evening (in case the activation process simply takes longer...)

Comment: If anything is deactivated due to missing or wrong settings, then it usually says so right next to the disabled button. It might simply be that this part of review is currently on hold, same as is the case for much of the other review stuff (access to data for pages, groups, ...) https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes

Comment: I have no idea what the problem is. It's still not working. I tried to invite others to my Facebook Page and test on their devices. Ads show, but I don't get the green checkmark on Facebook :( Any other Ideas are highly appreciated as I didn't get a response form the Facebook-Support so far :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the Problem after trying every single Setting on the Facebook page...
The problem was that I added my device as Test-Device.

So after removing `FBAdSettings.addTestDevice(FBAdSettings.testDeviceHash())` it was working.

Did cost my a lot of time and nerves :) But now everything works as expected!